# How to use more than one class modifier in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

i have already wrote a class to customize my model in django admin (extends from **admin.ModelAdmin**),but now i want to use a rich-text editor for my TextFields in that model(needs to extends from **SummernoteModelAdmin**), i don't know how to apply both of them.

in admin.py

```
admin.site.register(my_model, my_modelA)
```

i've tried this:

```
admin.site.register(my_model, my_modelA, my_modelB)
```

but it shows an error:

```
TypeError: register() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

how can i use both of those classes ?
Thanks~

Comment: @Sayse i added the error message, thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got it right `my_modelA` & `my_modelB` are subclasses of `admin.ModelAdmin` and you want your `my_model`'s admin to inherit from both.

You could implement a third admin class `my_modelC` like this:

```py
class my_modelC(my_modelA, my_modelB):
   pass

admin.site.register(my_model, my_modelC)
```

Comment: You made my day sir! thanks, that solved my problem <3